# Sharing articles on Linkedin

Tags: linkedin-api

I'm trying to make a simple link for sharing articles on Linkedin. For example:

```html
  <a href="https://www.linkedin.com/sharing/share-offsite/?url=http://localhost:3000/ClassReadOnly/groupmessage966f351893404b76b7546a561044ca73">Linkedin</a>
```

But I'm getting an error:
[image]

And in the console:

```
6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:2291 Error while processing route: inshare.index Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview [inshare-common/routes/index] Error: Ember Data Request GET /voyager/api/contentcreation/urlPreview [inshare-common/routes/index]
    at https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/dw3m6924dec632qi6ure12fs0:189:561
    at b (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:7246:12)
    at g (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:7245:3)
    at p (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:7232:1)
    at invokeWithOnError (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:6116:199)
    at d.flush (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:6100:20)
    at p.flush (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:6128:52)
    at B._end (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:6229:9)
    at B._boundAutorunEnd (https://static-exp1.licdn.com/sc/h/6oydvamu0ccyz6bjubzwr4zq1:6166:6)
```

I get the same result in a dev environment, so it's not because of `localhost`

What do I have to do to make it work as it should?